# Count the number of contiguous subarrays with maximum element as x

Tags: stack, sub-array

Given an array of numbers, print the number of subarrays with maximum element as x. For example :

```
Input :
arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1]
x = [3,2,1,4]

output : 11,2,2,0

Subarrays for x = 1: 
1
1

Subarrays for x = 2: 
2
1 2 

Subarrays for x = 3: 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 3 
1 2 3 3 1 
2 3 
2 3 3 
2 3 3 1 
3 
3 3 
3 3 1 
3 
3 1
```

There are no subarray with maximum element as 4. So for x = 4 we have to print 0.

My first attempt was to generate all subarrays and count that.The time complexity of this approach is very bad(`O(n^3)`)

Comment: Is `11` correct answer though?

Comment: No because 1 1 is not a contiguous subarray

Comment: I meant when `x = 3` is `11` the correct number of sub-arrays you can create? And when `x = 3` shouldn't `2` and `1` be valid sub-array as well, because `3` is considered to be a valid sub-array.

Comment: No because 3 is not in  `2` and `1` subarrays.

Comment: Does the sequence of `arr` matter? Do you have to print `11` only or do you also have to print sub-arrays?

Comment: Yes the sequence of `arr` does matter and we only have to print the number of subarrays that satisfy this condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231484/discussion-between-linux-geek-and-emma-funkhouser).